# How to add to a JPanel from another class

Tags: java, swing

I've been spending the past few hours trying to figure out how to use a panel in my `GUI` class from a class named `algorithms`. I know this question has been asked before, But I cant seem to figure out how to incorporate it into my code, so I would appreciate any form of guidance.

Specifically, in my algorithms class I was testing trying to change the JLabel named title by creating a instance of my GUI class and then trying to use `title.setText()`, however it returns a Null Pointer Exception.

The `title` JLabel is located on my JPanel named `topPanel`

I know I'm not doing something right, I've struggled with this for the past few hours and cant seem to make any progress. Like I said, any guidance would be appreciated.

`GUI.java`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public JFrame myFrame;
    public JPanel firstFitDisplay,topPanel;
    public JLabel title;
    public Timer timer;
    public int count=0;


    public GUI(){



    }


    public void initGUI(){


        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setTitle("CIS 452 Dynamic Memory Allocation Project");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setResizable(true);
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6,6));
        myFrame.setSize(1000,700);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        //myFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

        //setup panels
        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        bottom.setBackground(Color.pink);
        infoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,1000));
        centerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,20));
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,25));



        //setup layout for panels, so that we can add subpanels
        infoPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(infoPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        //add panels to main frame
        myFrame.add(infoPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        myFrame.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myFrame.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        myFrame.add(bottom,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        // setup sub panels for infoPanel
        JPanel infoSubPanel = new JPanel();
        infoSubPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
        infoSubPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,90));
        infoPanel.add(infoSubPanel);
        //setting up text for infoSubPanel
        JLabel subPanelTitle = new JLabel("Next Process Size to be allocated");
        JLabel firstFitNextUpLabel = new JLabel("First:0");
        JLabel bestFitNextUpLabel = new JLabel("Best:0");
        JLabel worstFitNextUpLabel = new JLabel("Worst:0");
        infoSubPanel.add(subPanelTitle);
        infoSubPanel.add(firstFitNextUpLabel);
        infoSubPanel.add(bestFitNextUpLabel);
        infoSubPanel.add(worstFitNextUpLabel);
        //subClockPanel
        JPanel infoSubClockPanel = new JPanel();
        infoSubClockPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        infoSubClockPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,90));
        infoPanel.add(infoSubClockPanel);

        //setting up text for sub clock panel
        JLabel clockText = new JLabel("Seconds passed: ");
        int ten = 10;
        JLabel clockCounter = new JLabel("0");
        infoSubClockPanel.add(clockText);
        infoSubClockPanel.add(clockCounter);


        //logic for running timer;
        timer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
            clockCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count++));
        });
        timer.start();

        //setting up sub panels for the main center panel
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel firstFitDisplay = new JPanel();
        JPanel bestFitDisplay = new JPanel();
        JPanel worstFitDisplay = new JPanel();
        firstFitDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
        bestFitDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
        worstFitDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
        centerPanel.add(firstFitDisplay);
        centerPanel.add(bestFitDisplay);
        centerPanel.add(worstFitDisplay);
        //center components
        centerPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        firstFitDisplay.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


        //setup title
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Dynamic Memory Allocation Simulator");
        topPanel.add(title);



    }
}
```

and here is `algorithms.java`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class algorithms {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI f = new GUI();
        f.initGUI();
        f.title.setText("HHHHHHHHHHH");
    }



}
```

Comment: You are never assigning to the member ```title```, instead you made a local variable with that same name.  You made that mistake throughout your code with many fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your mistake is that you never define title in your GUI class. I think you intended to with this line:

```java
JLabel title = new JLabel("Dynamic Memory Allocation Simulator");
```

This actually creates a new local variable called title instead of defining the global one. So the global variable is still null. To fix this simply change that to like to this:

```java
this.title = new JLabel("Dynamic Memory Allocation Simulator");
```

Now it will define the global variable! This shouldn't give a null pointer exception now.

Comment: Thank you! I have a follow up question,  Say I made a Jpanel in my algorithms class, and wanted to add that panel to infoSubPanel in my GUI class, how would that be achieved with writing the code in my algorithms class??

Comment: Never mind, I tried doing the same approach but just with a panel and it seemed to do the trick :) !